# Laravel 9 phpstan

Tags: laravel, phpstan

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot call method getClientOriginalExtension() on array<int, Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile>|Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile|null.
```

when I run phpstan

this's  code:

```
$imageName = time() . '.' . $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->file('image')->move(base_path() . '/public/uploads/', $imageName);
```

I tried adding `$request->file('image')[0]->getClientOriginalExtension();` but did't fix it

Comment: You can probably force a type on the `$request->file('image')` by saving it into a variable `$file` before that code and type inting it by adding `/** @var UploadedFile $file */` above it.

Comment: this error is showing ```PHPDoc tag @var above a method has no effect.```

Comment: not above the method, above the new variable `$file = $request->file('image');`, to then be used as `$imageName = time() . '.' .  $file->getClientOriginalExtension();` & `$file->move(...);`

Comment: yes, I was apply ```$imageName = time() . '.' .  $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); & $file->move(...);``` and I got the same error

Comment: ```Cannot call method getClientOriginalExtension() on array<int, Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile>|Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile|null.```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because `getClientOriginalExtension` does not exist in this union type: `array<int, Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile>|Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile|null` This union type is used because static analysis cannot know if `$request->file('image')` will return one file, array of files, or `null`

So first of all you can do a `null` check. The file you are trying to get might not exist.

```php
$file = $request->file('image');

if ($file === null) {
    // Handle this case
}
```

Then, you can check if there were multiple files or just one:

```php
if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
    // It's one file
} else {
    // It's an array of files
}
```

But if in your use case you are sure that for example it's always one file, you can do this instead:

```php
/** @var \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile $file */
$file = $request->file('image');
```